# Opening /etc/syslog-ng/syslog.conf

Tags: syslog

I understand that the above is a text file and I want to open in for editing. I am using:

```
sudo /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf
```

How must I modify this command?

Comment: `sudo <text editor you want to use> /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf` (you can use `gedit` for example). `sudo /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf` will try to execute that text file as a superuser.

Comment: I have done that , i installed gedit and modified my command but now it says sudo:gedit:command not found

Comment: @sosytee gedit is installed by default. Maybe you uninstalled it.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu i have to direct this question to you, i hope you can help, what do i do if i nolonger have that configuration file for syslog-ng. Due to low familiarity with vi editor, i made one too many mistakes and i then removed the file. I was assuming uninstalling and reinstalling syslog-ng would be the solution, but it seems that file is gone

Comment: @sosytee This may help you: http://www.slideshare.net/balabit/syslogng-configuration-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Salem](https://askubuntu.com/users/33871/salem) said in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322876/opening-etc-syslog-ng-syslog-conf#comment410516_322876), you should use:

```
sudo -i
gedit /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf
```

to open in a GUI editor.

Or

```
sudo vi /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf
```

to edit right in terminal.